# How to verify that the star ratings are highlighted on mouse hover through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

i am working on a scenario where I move mouse cursor to 5-star rating, and I have to verify that previous stars are highlighted.

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="wh-rating-choices">
    <div class="wh-rating-choices-holder">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <em>Your Rating: <span></span></em>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hover over 3rd star, previous 2 stars and current 3rd star are highlighted and last 2 stars are not highlighted, and the change in HTML is this:

```
<div class="wh-rating-choices">
    <div class="wh-rating-choices-holder">
        <a class="hover" href="#">1</a>
        <a class="hover" href="#">2</a>
        <a class="hover" href="#">3</a>
        <a class="" href="#">4</a>
        <a class="" href="#">5</a>
        <em>Your Rating: <span></span></em>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the class addition.

Is there any way I can verify this html change (to check that only first 3 stars are highlighted and last 2 stars are not highlighted)?

Currently my script is able to move to any of the star and click it. But I am not comprehending how to verify the star highlight feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
// wait 2 seconds until `hover` classes will load
Thread.sleep(2000)

// find all elements with hover class
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='hover']"));
```

Then simple logic will be like this: if `List` size is 3, then everything is ok. If you want to make sure, that exactly 1-3 stars are highlighted, you can loop through the list and get text of elements.

```
int starsExpected = 3;
if (elements.size() != starsExpected){
    throw new Exception("There is an error with stars highlight occurred");
}

for (WebElement e : elements){
   String text = e.getText(); // get current element text, like `1`, `2`... `5`
   if(Integer.parseInt(text) > starsExpected){ 
      throw new Exception("There is an error with stars highlight occurred");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write method that counts stars for control:

```
public int countStars(){
    return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='hover']"));
}
```

so You could do following:

highlight your stars, and assert it with above written method:

```
int expectedCnt = 3;
Assert.assertEquals(countStars(), expectedCnt, "Count should be equal!")
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* of before and after *Mouse Hover* event, the difference is the presence of **class="hover"** within the child `<a>` tags. So to verify that the *previous stars are highlighted* you can create a *List* inducing *WebDriverWait* for the desired elements and validate if the *List* is **non-empty** and you can use the following solution:

```
//Perform Mouse Hover
if ((new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']//a[@class='hover']")))).size() != 0)
    System.out.println("Previous Stars are highlighted");
else
    System.out.println("Previous Stars are not highlighted");
```